# Malware injection in site, how to remedy?

Tags: javascript, web, inject, malware

I have a big problem. The website that I look after has gotten infected. That being said, my problem is that I cannot find the source of this infection. My javascript files appear to be clean. My PHP is clean. The weird thing is that the injection occurs in all the .html files as well as in all the .php files. My .php has no link to any other outside scripts. So, it can't be the javascript, right?

this is the example that I get:

This is my page: http://www.activewatch.info/

I am using a hosting plan from godaddy (if that helps)

I am interested about finding out if my server is the problem or if it is the files I have uploaded.

**Your opinions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.**

Ps, I
've posted this on google support forums and sent an email to my host, explaining my situation.

Comment: What JS/PHP code is being injected? Could you provide the source code/proof of what is being changed? Also, try to avoid "opinions". Ask a question and people will comment/answer :). I noticed that you included `jquery.min.js` and jquery from Google CDN. Also, you are adding jquery plugins **before** the jquery lib and that may cause some issues.

Comment: Someone, removed the code I pasted into the original question. It looked something like this '<!--random numbers--> <script src="randomdomain.ru/file.js"></script><!--same random numbers-->' and it was inserted under the </nav> tag. In case of the php it was similar but inserted into the ending php tag. Ps. thank you for the jquery hint, i will modify it.

Answer (score 0):

it's said it fail to load

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://www.activewatch.info/js/script.js
>   Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

did you put it properly ? check this 2 links

http://www.activewatch.info/js/jquery.easing.min.js

http://www.activewatch.info/js/script.js

Comment: also, which part that you got infect, could you add more detail ?

Comment: Someone, removed the code I pasted into the original question. It looked something like this <!--random numbers--> <script src="http://randomdomain.ru/file.js"></script><!--same random numbers--> and it was inserted under the </nav> tag. The 2 links missing are javascripts that i have removed and forgot to update the html.